# How large is the Irken Armada?

Tags: invader-zim, irken

In Invader Zim, we see the Irken Armada, led by the *Massive*. While browsing the Invader Zim Wiki, I saw that it does not have any number of ships listed. Does anyone know the amount of ships that are in the Armada?